# How I can make transfer location data to another class?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = LocationManager()
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    private override init() {
        
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        
    }
    
}
extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let locations = locations.first else { return }
        
        let latitude = locations.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = locations.coordinate.longitude

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locations) { placemarks, error in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error in reverseGeocode")
            }
            
            guard let placemark = placemarks else { return }
            
            if placemark.count > 0 {
                guard let placemark = placemark.first else { return }
                
                guard let city = placemark.locality else { return }
                guard let country = placemark.country else { return }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        
    }
    
}
```

I have got data from location manager, and I would like transfer city, country, latitude, longitude data to another class, how I can make it?

Comment: Explain the relationship between the class where you get data and the class where it's going to be used.

Comment: Protocol/delegate, a callback closure or a Combine publisher are the common ways.